# After Trump, who is responsible for the executive?

Tags: united-states, constitution

There are, more or less, debates about Trump impeachment. Assume Trump to be fired, but at the same time vice president misses [presidential qualifications](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/26644/are-there-any-ways-besides-death-for-a-sitting-us-president-to-be-dismissed-au).
What then?
Who is responsible for the executive?

Comment: The VP can’t hold office unless they have the qualifications needed to be President.

Answer (score 5):

There's no reason to believe the [normal line of succession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_line_of_succession) wouldn't be followed, so the next person would be the Speaker of the House, Paul Ryan.  The only position in the line of succession that is currently filled by a person ineligible to become President is the Secretary of Transportation.   [Elaine Chao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elaine_Chao), the Secretary of Transportation, was born in Taiwan.

Answer (score 2):

The premise of the question is flawed, because the Vice President can't miss the qualifications to be President. Reference the 12th Amendment to the Constitution:

> ...But no person constitutionally ineligible to the office of President shall be eligible to that of Vice-President of the United States.

Meaning
 - Be a natural-born U.S. citizen
 - Be at least 35 years old
 - Have resided in the U.S. at least 14 years

Comment: why  "Vice President can't miss the qualifications to be President."? consider: death.

Comment: @user1 Why yes, being alive is a necessary part of being alive. If the vice president is dead, he certainly isn't going to assume the presidency.